# What is the connection between these two notions of a "vector field"?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, physics, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

I'm reading a physics text which dives into some mathematical concepts that are new to me. Consider a function $F(q,\dot q)$ (dynamical variable) where here $q$ and $\dot q$ represent sets of local generalized position coordinates $q^\alpha$ and velocity coordinates $\dot q^\alpha$. A dot above indicates a total time derivative ($\dot F = dF/dt$). Thus,

$$\dot F (q , \dot q) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q^\alpha} \dot q^\alpha + \frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot q^\alpha} \ddot q^\alpha.$$

Here, the Einstein summation convention is assumed, implying a summation over the index $\alpha$. In general, the equations of motion for a particular physical system provide a function $\ddot q^\alpha  = \ddot q^\alpha (q, \dot q)$, so the above equality is indeed strictly a function on only $q$ and $\dot q$.

Now, my textbook generalizes this derivative into an operator $\Delta$, which send functions on $(q, \dot q)$ to other functions on $(q, \dot q)$.

$$\Delta = \dot q^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial q^\alpha} +  \ddot q^\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q^\alpha}$$

This allows us to write

$$\dot F = \Delta F.$$

My textbook proceeds to refer to $\Delta$ as a **vector field** and additionally generalizes the notion of a vector field $X$ on $(q, \dot q)$ as

$$X = X^\alpha_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial q^\alpha} + X^\alpha_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q^\alpha},$$

where the $X_1^\alpha$ and $X_2^\alpha$ are functions on $(q, \dot q)$.

My current understanding of the term **vector field** is something like an electric field, where every point in a space is associated with a vector. Can anyone explain to me how these two notions of vector field are related? Why is my textbook referring to $X$ and $\Delta$ as vector fields when they act as operators and are not vector-valued?

Comment: You should read the notion of vector fields on modern differential geometry text. Such as Lee’smooth manifold or Tu’s intro to manifod, Marsden or Nakahara if you prefer.

Comment: Would the $X\mathbf x$ then be the equivalent set of vectors, where $\mathbf x$ are the points in the manifold described by $(q, \dot q)$?.

Comment: If you have a vector, you can take the directional derivative along that vector. If you have an operator that behaves like a directional derivative, you can obtain the corresponding vector by applying it to the coordinate functions. So vectors and directional derivative operators are the same thing. What they have there is a directional derivative operator at every point, which is equivalent to (and what differential geometers define as) a vector field.

Comment: Sorry, I just deleted and reposted my comment after editing.

Comment: If you like, you can think of $X_i^\alpha$ as the components of the vector field along the basis vectors $\partial/\partial q^\alpha$ and $\partial/\partial\dot q^\alpha$.

Comment: @Rahul: Your first comment is complete enough to post as answer. Would you please do that?